# Swing setText() to a label not working in another system

Tags: java, swing, awt, gettext, settext

I have a Java Swing application which runs properly in my computer.  When the same is run on another system, the application runs but the following errors occur:

1. `getText()`, `setText()` not working.
2. Command prompt shows error `awt event queue error 0" ,class not found exception` etc.. This is a id card printing application

Can someone help me solve these errors?

Comment: At least post the full stack trace of the exception and describe the `getText`/`setText` not working part in a bit more detail

Comment: It can be some version conflict, though without full __StackTrace__, it's a bit hard to comment on the topic.... Don't you think, the person on the other side, is not always a fortune teller? :-)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).